# What is best practise for dimensionality reduction in rows of data

Tags: r, machine-learning, dataset, dimensionality-reduction

I was wondering what was best practise for dimensionality reduction in observations (as opposed to features) in a data-set? I often have data comprising of a multiple, random number of observations per participant. For example the data may look like this (R code).

```
set.seed(999)
df <- NULL
for(i in 1:10){
  n_rows <- sample(1:10, 1)
  temp_df <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(n_rows),
                    x2 = runif(n_rows),
                    x3 = sample(c('A','B','C','D'), n_rows, replace = TRUE),
                    participant = sprintf('participant%s',i),
                    y = sample(c('yes','no'), 1))
  df <- rbind(df, temp_df)
}
```

I want to model these data, for example to predict from x1, x2 and x3 which participant will be y == 'yes' and y == 'no'. I therefore need to produce 1 row of data from the multiple rows relating to each participant. I could just take be mean (or max/min/etc.) of each column (windowed by participant)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(y) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

Or, i could arbitrarily combine rows

```
df %>% group_by(y) %>% summarise(a1 = mean(x1) + mean(x2),
                                 a2 = max(x2) * 3)
```

Which both reduce the observations per participant to 1. But are there better ways to do this? I feel like i'm losing to much information using this procedure. What is best practise under these circumstances?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you "therefore need to produce 1 row of data from the multiple rows relating to each participant"? Why not just use the multiple rows directly?

Comment: Because each row is not an independent observation. A series of rows represent a series of events which occurred for each participant. I want to predict each participants unique 'y' from those series of events. It doesn't make sense to make a prediction for each row.

Comment: Do you want to perform hypothesis tests, or just predict Y? There is no problem for a pure predictive model. If you want hypothesis tests, is there a reason not to account for unit effects with a random effect (eg a GLMM)?

Comment: I just want to be predictive, but i want to only report 1 y prediction per participant. If i just plough ahead, ill get a different prediction of y for every observation relating to each participant. I suppose i could do this and use a majority vote to define the unique y for every participant

Comment: My guess is that it's better to average the predictions than to average the x-values, but that's an interesting question. What type of model did you intend to use?

Comment: So far i'm not sure, probably just the basic supervised learning algorithms. Lasso, random forest, svm, etc.